# ShellExecute fails: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, shellexecute, admin-rights

I'm trying to start my application with my own launcher with administrator rights. The launcher works on my **64Bit Win7** but not at my **32Bit WinXP** computer.
The code I am using is this:

```
wstring fullAppPath = "myapp.exe";
ShellExecuteW(NULL,
             L"runas",                       //admin rights
             fullAppPath.c_str(),
             NULL,                           //startup params
             NULL,                           //default dir
             SW_SHOWNORMAL
             );
```

I use the MSVC 2010 32Bit compiler with the Qt IDE and the launcher-application and the main-application are in the same directory, which is not *C:\Windows\System32*.
On my WinXP computer I get anytime I start my launcher an ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error. (value *2*)
How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslash, i.e. `"C:\\myapp.exe"`?

Comment: Of course I tried. To be exact I used a relative path.

Comment: That might sound obvious but is myapp.exe a 64-bit app? Also, does it work if you replace myapp.exe with e.g. notepad.exe?

Comment: Using relative paths is never not a mistake.  Using SetCurrentDirectory() is required so you *know* where Windows starts looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I was looking for the error for about one week. I'm wondering how the solution could be that easy. :) But why has it been working on Win7 and not on WinXP?